# JavaScript string tel parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, string, parsing

I have a set of string like this:

```
"Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet, 6:13 p.m - <a href='tel:5555'>555-5</a> / <a href='tel:7777'>777-7</a>"
```

The amount of `<a></a>` tag is variable, in my example I need return "5555" and "7777"

What and how  is the best way to do that in JavaScript?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the inner text or the attribute? And are you having trouble accessing it or stripping out non-numbers?

Comment: @Anthony see FelixKling answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply let JS (or jQuery) parse the HTML, find the `a` elements and read their `href` properties.

E.g.

```
var hrefs = $($.parseHTML(str)).filter('a').map(function() {
   return this.href;
}).get();
// gives an array like ['tel:5555', 'tel:7777'] which you can process further
```

All in all, to make it more reliable and extract the numbers, you can do:

```
function parseTel(str) {
  str = '<div>' + str + '</div>';
  return $($.parseHTML(str)).find('a[href^="tel:"]').map(function() {
    return +this.href.split(':')[1];
 }).get();
}
```

Comment: Excellent, seems just what I need.
How I can turn it into a function that takes `str` and return the `href` array ?

Comment: `function extractTel(str) { return $(...)....get(); }`